# How do you cache a variable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If I'm constantly referencing:

```
$('#' + n + ':nth-child(2)').val()
```

then how do I cache $('#' + n) into a variable?

```
$n = $('#' + n);
$n:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: What is the value of `n`? Is it simply the ID? Does it include a trailing space character? These details will make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
$n = $('#' + n);
$n.find(":nth-child(2)");
```

Comment: If `n` is just an ID like `"myID"`, then the original selector looks like `"#myID:nth-child(2)"`, which doesn't include the *descendant selector*. In that case, using `.find()` is different from the original. We can't really know for sure without knowing the value of `n`.

Comment: I think I liked this solution better because it's a little more self-documenting.  More obvious what the selector is doing.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var $n = $('#' + n); 
var $child = $(":nth-child(2)", $n);
```

Comment: Note to OP: you'll see the $ in front of variables that represent jQuery objects. This is a nice convention.

Comment: Personally, I hate the $ in front of variables for jQuery objects. Maybe it just reminds me too much of PHP.

Comment: Because of the way [jQuery implements selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) it may be faster to use `$($n).find(':nth-child(2)');` Albeit I suspect the difference is likely to be minor, at best.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.filter()`, which applies the selector to elements at the root of the jQuery object instead of `.find()` or the context parameter, which search inside the elements at the root.

```
var $n = $('#' + n);
var second = $n.filter(':nth-child(2)');
```

That is assuming that the initial selector in your question evaluates to something like:

```
$('#someID:nth-child(2)')
```

If it is, it would concern me a little since there should only be one element with `someID`.

To give a more certain answer, we would need to know the value of `n`.

Comment: Using .filter() won't necessarily return the same result as his original selector since it doesn't include children. A subsequent action on `second` might not work the same as an action on the original $n.

Comment: @jamietre: Unless the structure changes, it would be the same. Either the `# + n` element is an `:nth-child(2)` or it isn't. It is just odd to specify `nth-child` on an element when there can be only one on the page.

Comment: I was slowly coming to that understanding when your comment appeared :) True, I was thinking about the question more generally not in the context of nth-child.